# How can I populate a search index using SitePage query?

Tags: graphql, gatsby

I'm trying to implement search in my gastby blog. I've seen many tutorials and plugins but they all use Markdown, my blog is built with strapi and the pages are created dynamically. I realised the node allSitePage could give all the information I needed for the search index, I tried to use it in the flexsearch plugin like this in gatsby-config.js :

```js
{
      resolve: "gatsby-plugin-flexsearch",
      options: {
        languages: ["en"],
        type: "allSitePage",
        fields: [
          {
            name: "title",
            indexed: true,
            resolver: "fields.title",
            attributes: {
              encode: "balance",
              tokenize: "strict",
              threshold: 6,
              depth: 3,
            },
            store: true,
          },
          {
            name: "context",
            indexed: true,
            resolver: "fields.context",
            attributes: {
              encode: "balance",
              tokenize: "strict",
              threshold: 6,
              depth: 3,
            },
            store: false,
          },
          {
            name: "url",
            indexed: false,
            resolver: "fields.path",
            store: true,
          },
        ],
      },
    },
```

but my index is empty. Any ideas on how to make it work or easier alternatives?

Answer (score 1):

if anyone is still looking into this:

- remove "all" in the type (so, from "allSitePage" to "SitePage")
- remove "fields." in the resolver definitions (so, from "fields.title" to "title")

After the changes the code by OP should look like:

```
    {
      resolve: "gatsby-plugin-flexsearch",
      options: {
        languages: ["en"],
        type: "SitePage",
        fields: [
          {
            name: "title",
            indexed: true,
            resolver: "title",
            attributes: {
              encode: "balance",
              tokenize: "strict",
              threshold: 6,
              depth: 3,
            },
            store: true,
          },
          {
            name: "context",
            indexed: true,
            resolver: "context",
            attributes: {
              encode: "balance",
              tokenize: "strict",
              threshold: 6,
              depth: 3,
            },
            store: false,
          },
          {
            name: "url",
            indexed: false,
            resolver: "path",
            store: true,
          },
        ],
      },
    },
```